# DynamicDNS SSH Forwarding: Authentication Not Working

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I've just setup dynamic DNS, in an effort to be able to access my home desktop from anywhere. This seems to be set up correctly, and as testing I've forwarded port 22 on my router to port 22 on my desktop.

However, when I try to SSH into the machine:

```
ssh username@hostname.ddns.net
```

I get the permission denied error after entering my password:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

The fact that I'm getting asked for a password obviously means that my key pair isn't working either.

I have no idea what's going on here. Clearly *something* is accepting my SSH request, and as the only thing I've set up I'm assuming it must be my computer. But it's not accepting my key pair, nor my password.

Any ideas as to what might be up?

Comment: Done some more digging and found the issue - I guess port forwarding on my router isn't working? I have a modem/router combo, and it's trying to get me to SSH into the modem bit rather than forwarding the request to my desktop (I can actually log in to the modem this way). Not sure how to fix this?

Comment: forward a different port? or fix your router so it's only listening on LAN for ssh

Comment: Are you connecting **from inside** of your LAN or from outside? This sounds like a very common "NAT hairpin" issue unrelated to DNS.